# Optional property based on whether the generic type is passed

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, conditional-types

How to make an interface so that when `T` is passed, `a` is typed `T`, and when it's not passed, `a` can be optional (a missing property), for instance:

```
interface A<T = void> {
  a: T
}

const a1: A<string> = { a: 'a' } //  No error, good

const a2: A = {}

//  Should not throw
// "Property 'a' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'A<void>'.ts(2741)"
```

The only problem with the following approach is that `a` can't be missed from the object:

```
interface A<T = void> {
  a: T extends void ? undefined : T
}

const a3: A = {}

//  TS throws
// "Property 'a' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'A<void>'. ts(2741)"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not have `undefined` as default type for `T`?

Otherwise, you can have conditional types:

```
interface A<T = void> {
    a: T extends void ? undefined : T
}
```

To avoid having a required property with a type of undefined and remove the property completely, try using types instead:

```
type A<T = void> = T extends void ? Record<string, never> : { a: T }
```

... where `Record<string, never>` is a fancy way of denoting an empty object (don't use `{}`, which means “any non-nullish value”, and would thus accept also e.g. a string). If you then  need additional properties that are always there in addition to `a`, you can write stuff like:

```
type A<T = void> = T extends void ? Record<string, never> : { a: T } & { b: number }
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```